# Where do you add code in custom fuctions so it works on a specific page?

Tags: theme-development, conditional-content, code

Thanks for replying but I still can't get it to work. Is anything wrong with this code?

```
   <?php

class custom_loop extends thesis_custom_loop {
function page() {
if(is_page( array('career-work','happiness'))) {
      global $thesis_design;
$thesis_design->home['body']['content']['features'] = 0;
$thesis_design->display['archives']['style'] = 'teasers';
$thesis_design->image['thumb']['y'] = 'after-headline';
$thesis_design->teasers['options']['date']['show'] = 0;
$thesis_design->teasers['options']['excerpt']['show'] = 1;  
    global $wp_query;
    $saved_query = $wp_query;
    thesis_loop::page();
    wp_reset_query();
    $args = array('category_in' => array(59,'62));
    $loop = query_posts("cat=59,62");
    thesis_loop::home();
    wp_reset_query();
    $wp_query = $saved_query;
} else
    thesis_loop::page();
}
}
$custom_loop = new custom_loop();
```

The code above is to show teasers on a specific page. It obviously works for one page but where do I add this code, or what do I change it to, in order for it to work for any page I specify?

I've tried creating a new PHP file in my theme and copying and pasting the code (changing the category ID etc) but it won't work.

Thanks

Comment: I can't really follow what you're trying to do here. You've pasted your code, which is good; but it needs context. Can you explain, in human terms, what you're trying to accomplish? Are you trying to output content conditionally on specific pages? If so, where are you defining your custom function, and where are you *outputting* that custom function?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing ' in your if statement. Then it should work, and you can use comma to specify various IDs or slugs for pages.

```
if(is_page('health-fitness')) {
```

Try this.

Comment: Thanks for replying but I stil can't get it to work. I edited the code above (as a new user I can't reply to my own question). Do you see anything wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

One problem is your [`is_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) syntax:

```
<?php
if(is_page('career-work','health-fitness'))
?>
```

The `is_page()` conditional can only take *one* parameter. If you need to pass multiple values to the conditional, they must be wrapped in an *array*, e.g.:

```
<?php
if( is_page( array( 'career-work','health-fitness' ) ) )
?>
```

I don't know if that will completely solve your problem, but it is definitely one issue.

Comment: Thanks I'm almost there... I added the code you gave me, but as you would expect the code specifies to pull the content from both slugs and categories instead of having different content on different pages. I changed the code again at the top btw.

Comment: I'm not sure you totally understand how `is_page()` works. The `is_page()` template tag doesn't "*pull content*" from anything; it's simply a *conditional* (i.e. Boolean) tag, that returns `true` or `false`, based on an evaluation of the current context against the `$page` parameter passed to it.

Comment: I've been trying for hours to try and sort this out but no luck. Can anyone please help me? All I want to do is display teasers from the post content from certain categories which I can then display onto any page I specify. It sounds as if it would be quite a common question and easy to rectify but I can't find anything on the internet to help.

Comment: How do you define the teasers? How do you determine/define the category/categories of posts for which to return teasers? How do you determine on *which* static Pages, *which* teasers to display?